# fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory in VScode

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-code

```
#include "mysql.h"
```

This is my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\include",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\\include"
      ],
      "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
      "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
      "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "cStandard": "c17",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Error is:

mysql.cpp:2:10: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
#include "mysql.h"

compilation terminated.

How to solve this problem? Any solution?

Comment: The compiler does not look at c_cpp_properties.json, you need to edit tasks.json and edit the compiler options there to add the include path for your header file (second time today this question has been asked).

Comment: `{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": ["-o", "-Imysql", "mysql", "-g", "mysql.cpp"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}`
here is my task.json file

Comment: Well `"-Imysql"` is the option that is telling the compiler where to look for header files. Sorry but I have no experience of running g++ on Windows, so I'm not sure what it should be instead.

Comment: Also `"-o"` option is wrong. If you want to call the program mysql, then the options should be `"-o", "mysql", "-Imysql"` The way you have it you're going to get a program called `-Imysql`.